# Launch Activity from Lockscreen-Widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

is there a way to launch a activity from the Lockscreen-Widget so that the user does not need to login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and be careful what you expose